# Ramification of ray class field/ ring class field

Tags: number-theory, class-field-theory

Suppose $K$ is a number field. Let $q$ be a prime of $K$. Let $ K [q] $ be the ray class field of $K$ of modulus $q$. Someone claims that $K[q]$ is totally ramified at $q$ over the hilbert class field of $K$.

Moreover, in Gross and Zagier's paper about Kolyvagin's work on modular elliptic curves, there is a similar result. Suppose $l$ is a prime. Then the ring class field of an imaginary quadratic field $K$ of modulus $l$ is totally ramified at $l$ over the hilbert class field of $K$.

Both results are claimed that they can be solved by class field theory. However I don't know how to see it.

Comment: If I’m not mistaken, it’s a paper by Gross only. The Gross-Zagier paper is a different result (if no less remarkable). Anyway, what do you know about class field theory? What have you tried?

Comment: Honestly, I don't know how to deal with the problem at all. As I know, class field theory tells very little about total ramification. For a prime $v$, the image of $K_v^{\times}$ under the global Artin map gives the decomposition group of $v$ and the image of $O_v^{\times}$ gives the Inertia group. So to show totally ramification is equivalent to show the image of $K_{v}^{\times}$ is the whole galois group while the image of the inertia group is trivial. But I think it is not a good way for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that by *totally ramified at $q$* you mean that $K[q]/H$, where $H$ is the Hilbert class field of $K$, is ramified only at primes above $q$ and that no intermediate extension $K[q] \supset K' \supset H$ is unramified.

This follows from the description of $H$ as the maximal abelian everywhere unramified extension of $K$, and that $K[q]/K$ is the maximal abelian extension ramified only at primes above $q$. It follows that $K'$ is abelian over $K$ as well. If $K'/K$ was unramified, then this would contradict the maximality of $H$!

The same goes for the ring class field, which can be described as a subfield of the ray class field of the same modulus.

Comment: Is this description equivalent to: “for any prime $\mathfrak{q}$ of $H$ above $q$, the ramification index of $K[q]/H$ above $\mathfrak{q}$ is exactly $[K[q]:H]$”?

Comment: I don't think they are equivalent. I mean what Aphelli says.

Comment: Sorry! Here's an argument: set $G_q = \operatorname{Gal}(K[q]/K)$, and let $I_q \subset G_q$ be the inertia subgroup at $q$ (independent of prime above $q$ because everything is abelian). I claim that $K[q]^{I_q} = H$. The containment $\supset$ follows from $H$ being unramified, and $\subset$ since $K[q]^{I_q}$ is abelian and unramified everywhere. Then $I_q = \operatorname{ker}(G_q \to \operatorname{Gal}(H/K)) \cong \operatorname{Gal}(K_q/H)$, so any prime above $q$ is totally ramified.

Comment: I get what you mean. Thank you very much. It seems that I have mistaken something seeming trivial.